# Is there a way to exclude jobs from Gitlab stages?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a long gitlab CI in a mono repo kind of structure. It looks as follows:

```
Project A

    --- .gitlab-ci.yaml (contains thousands of jobs across 3 stages(plan, test and apply) and also includes gitlab-ci folder)
    --- gitlab-ci/my-ci.yaml (folder than contains specific ci files, this has 2 stages, plan and apply for my-new-code)
    --- my-new-code (folder which I recently pushed)
    --- other folders
```

I have added `my-ci.yaml` as a separate file to the `gitlab-ci` folder. But what happens is that those thousands of jobs from the `gitlab-ci.yaml` run along with the relevant job when I push changes only to `my-new-code` folder.

I understand that those jobs will run in the stages because they don't have any `rules/only/except` statements and it is impractical for me to add it to each one of them.

Is there a way I can exclude these jobs from running in the 2 stages when changes are made to the my-new-code folder?

Comment: Can you please confirm my understanding you want to run my-ci.yaml when commit made into my-new-code. If commit happens in other folder then other script should run?

Comment: Hi! yes I want jobs from my-ci.yml to run only when changes are pushed to my-new-code folder. When commits happen on the other folders, then jobs from .gitlab-ci.yaml should run and not from my-ci.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

You can have [changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) condition with folder or file names to it.

If you can see below the job will run only if specific changes made into src folder likewise you use for your jobs

```
test_pylint:
  stage: test
  image: python:3.7
  allow_failure: true
  before_script:
    - pip install pylint pylint-junit
    - pip install -e .
    - python -V
  script:
    - pylint --output-format=pylint_junit.JUnitReporter src/ | tee rspec.xml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - rspec.xml
    reports:
      junit: rspec.xml
    when: always
    expire_in: 1 week
  rules:
  - if: '($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event")'
    when: always
    changes:
      - src/**/*
```

If you want to exclude jobs based on folder consider using [except changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#onlychanges--exceptchanges-examples) as it would exclude that file/folder like below example which will not allow the job to run if any changes made into md files

```
build:
  script: npm run build
  except:
    changes:
      - "*.md"
```

PS: This is merge request pipelines you can frame the if condition for commit based pipelines

Comment: As i mentioned earlier, the problem with using ```changes``` is that it will not exclude other jobs which do not have any constraint defined. If I push my code to `my-new-code` folder, it will still add the other jobs to the stage.

Comment: I would suggest you to look into except changes option. Updated my answer as well